# imacros extract and remove unwanted text

Tags: javascript, regex, imacros, extract

Hi Im trying to extract a price and strip the extract of some unwanted text. So that "US $149.99" becomes "149.99"

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=NAME:donasub ATTR=ID:donaprice EXTRACT=TXT
SET donaprice  EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(\"US $\", \"\");")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\demo FILE=donafiles.csv
```

I still get the full string "US $149.99" in the extract. What am I not doing right.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to use `s = s.replace(/US\s*\$/, \"\");`.

Comment: Thanks but that throws an imacros 1100 error  wrong format of SET !

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special characters with `\\`. In this case it is "$"

`SET donaprice EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(\"US \\$\", \"\");")`

`'show your result before saving in prompt (popup box) good for checking results`

`PROMPT {{donaprice}}`

You are re-saving the original extract which is US $149.99 in this line:

```
`SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\demo FILE=donafiles.csv`
```

You have to re-add the new variable "donaprice" to `EXTRACT`

`ADD !EXTRACT {{donaprice}}`

`SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\demo FILE=donafiles.csv`

---

So all together :

`SET donaprice EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(\"US \\$\", \"\");")`

`ADD !EXTRACT {{donaprice}}`

`SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\demo FILE=donafiles.csv`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/US \\$/, ''); s;")
```