# imacros: How to remove suffix (@gmail.com) from email address extracted from .csv

Tags: javascript, string, csv, extract, imacros

I've only got the free version of imacros, so need non enterprise option.

I'm currently pulling email addresses from a .csv and want to just remove the suffix and use the rest as the username.  (so, joe@gmail.com would have username of "joe")

I've done some reading, and only answer I see without digging into scripting in paid version is here:

[imacros extract and remove unwanted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909301/imacros-extract-and-remove-unwanted-text)

Having trouble working it out, though as my example is a bit different.  I'm currently trying to work with:

```
SET !DATASOURCE /Users/Me/emails.csv
SET username EVAL("var s=???; s.replace(???)
ADD !EXTRACT {{username}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/join ATTR=ID:id_userName CONTENT={{username}}
```

Is that basically right?  except that I obviously need the syntax to complete second line?

A bit confused by other example and not clear if this is different since I am not extracting it from a site, but rather calling it via simple !COL1 from a local .csv file.  Does this change the ADD !Extract portion? and differ from the linked example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this piece of code. It must work for you.

```
' ...
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
SET username EVAL("'{{!COL1}}'.substr(0,'{{!COL1}}'.indexOf('@'));")
'PROMPT {{username}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/join ATTR=ID:id_userName CONTENT={{username}}
' ...
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you.